# NodeJs MySQL error on macOS: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_transform.js'

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

On Windows and Linux works good. On MacOS Monterey:

MySQL Error: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_transform.js'

**I did that, but it didn't help**

npm i mysql

up to date, audited 231 packages in 1s

39 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (1 low, 7 moderate)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Comment: What are you doing that generates this error?  Just the installation?  Or something else?